# How to remove all roles from a user?

Tags: users, flags

Users on my site generally have several roles.  However, every once in awhile I get a spam user, and so I close that account by flagging it with a **spam** flag, which triggers a rule to block the account.

Since I compile statistics on my site based on the number of users having a given role, I don't want spam users to be included.  How can I automatically remove all roles from spam users?  (I suppose I could add rules components to check for each role and remove it if found, but there has to be a more efficient way...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the user's roles and delete them.

```
/** @var \Drupal\user\UserInterface $user */
foreach ($user->getRoles() as $role) {
  $user->removeRole($role);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function can help you

```
/**
 * Remove a role from a user.
 *
 * @param $user
 *   User object or user ID.
 * @param $role_name
 *   String value of role to be removed.
 */
function custom_remove_role_from_user($user, $role_name) {
  // For convenience, we'll allow user ids as well as full user objects.
  if (is_numeric($user)) {
    $user = user_load($user);
  }
  // Only remove the role if the user already has it.
  $key = array_search($role_name, $user->roles);
  if ($key == TRUE) {
    // Get the rid from the roles table.
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);
    if ($rid != FALSE) {
      // Make a copy of the roles array, without the deleted one.
      $new_roles = array();
      foreach($user->roles as $id => $name) {
        if ($id != $rid) {
          $new_roles[$id] = $name;
        }
      }
      user_save($user, array('roles' => $new_roles));
    }
  }
}
```

first load user's roles, then call this function  something like

```
$user=user_load($uid);
foreach($user->roles as $role){
custom_remove_role_from_user($user, $role)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some quick code examples that I have used to add or remove user roles in Drupal 6. This can be very helpful if you are building a module for a specific site that has to manipulate user roles. Using this technique is not the most flexible solution as it limits itself to the roles configured on a specific site (based on role id and role name). However, you could easily add a database table and an administration section and make this more flexible if needed.

**Here is an easy way to add a role:**

//you will need to enter the uid of the user here, I am just using user 1

```
$user = user_load(1);
```

//first we check if the user has the role in question (using the rid of the role)

```
if (!isset($user->roles[7])) {
    //if not we add the role and set the role name based on what is entered
    //in the drupal role administration section
    $user->roles[7] = 'role name seven';
}
```

**Here is an easy way to remove a role:**

//you will need to enter the uid of the user here, I am just using user 1

```
$user = user_load(1);
```

//first we check if the user has the first role in question

```
if (isset($user->roles[8])) {

  //if so, we unset the role
  unset($user->roles[8]);

  $edit = array('roles' => $user->roles);
  user_save($user, $edit);
}
```

**Here is an easy way to do a role swap:**

//you will need to enter the uid of the user here, I am just using user 1

```
$user = user_load(1);



//first we check if the user has the first role in question
if (isset($user->roles[8])) {

  //if so, we unset the role
  unset($user->roles[8]);

  //now we check to see if they have the role we want to swap for
  if (!isset($user->roles[7])) {

    //if not we add this role
    $user->roles[7] = 'role name seven';
  }

  $edit = array('roles' => $user->roles);
  user_save($user, $edit);
}
```

Helpful? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this may help you

```
function user_role_delete($role) {

if (is_int($role)) {

        $role = user_role_load($role);

  }

else {

    $role = user_role_load_by_name($role);
  }


 db_delete('role')->condition('rid', $role->rid)->execute();

 db_delete('role_permission')->condition('rid', $role->rid)->execute();

 // Update the users who have this role set:

 db_delete('users_roles')->condition('rid', $role->rid)->execute();

  module_invoke_all('user_role_delete', $role);

  // Clear the user access cache.

 drupal_static_reset('user_access');

 drupal_static_reset('user_role_permissions');
}
```